# Javafx IllegalStateException

Tags: javafx, new-window

I'm trying to open a new window from my main screen and I keep getting IllegalStateException, Im really new to JavaFx and I still don't understand very well how the FXMLLoader works

here is my method

```
 @FXML
    public void openRegisterClientWindow(ActionEvent event) {

            try {

                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(RegisterClientDialogController.class.getResource("RegisterClientDialog.fxml"));
                AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();                

                Scene scene = new Scene(page);

                Stage stage = new Stage();



                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                textStatus.setText(e.getMessage());

            }

    }
```

here is the exception error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
file:/C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TSPMetodologia/dist/run1587747863/TSPMetodologia.jar!/tspmetodologia/dialogs/RegisterClientDialog.fxml:13
  at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.URLBuilder.build(URLBuilder.java:46)
  at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.URLBuilder.build(URLBuilder.java:17)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:582)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2464)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2169)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2061)
  at tspmetodologia.main.MainScreenController.openRegisterClientWindow(MainScreenController.java:140)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1444)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1449)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1444)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.URLBuilder.build(URLBuilder.java:46)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.URLBuilder.build(URLBuilder.java:17)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:582)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2464)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2061)
    at tspmetodologia.main.MainScreenController.openRegisterClientWindow(MainScreenController.java:140)
```

Comment: Post your fxml file also. Check if RegisterClientDialogController.class.getResource("RegisterClientDialog.fxml") is not null. Post probably it is null.

Comment: It looks like you might have registered this method as handling a mouse event, instead of an action event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is fine as long as your FXML reference is right, you can just try to use:

```
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(""RegisterClientDialog.fxml"))
```

instead of what you have if your controller and FXML are in the same package.

The error codes look like it may not be finding your FXML. So either the FXML .setlocation is not correct, your action event is not referenced in the FXML, or your controller is not referenced correctly in your FXML.